# look for nan in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nan

I have a pandas dataframe converted into a dictionary (OrderedDict) and now I need to look for real NaN values (not the 'nan' string values) without pandas/numpy methods (as it should be independent from these packages).
The dictionary looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([('concentration', ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', nan, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']),
 ('val', [6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, nan, nan, 0.0, 3.0, nan])])
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
keys = odict.keys()
count = len(odict[keys[0]])
for current in range(count):
        row = []
        for item in table:
            column = table[item]
            value = column[current]
            if >>>value is not nan<<<:
                row.append("MISSING")
            elif value is not None:
                row.append("value")
            else:
                row.append("something else")
        print(row)
```

Can anybody help?

**EDIT:**
The full solution for me is not so easy to find within the answers/comments from the duplicate question. That's why I add it here as a quote:

> ... Better to use a try/except construction:
>   **def is_nan(x): try: return math.isnan(x) except: return False** –  Rob

Comment: Use `math.isnan()` to see whether the value is nan or not.

Comment: but math.isnan() expects float values. I then get an error: TypeError: a float is required

Comment: Well, then you know it's not nan. Catch the exception and move on?

Comment: good idea. thanks. I'm not yet very deep into python. sorry for question with rather simple answers.